# Mysql Create table using Trigger

Tags: mysql, triggers

I have tried to create table inside the Mysql Trigger but not get created. How to create a table using trigger,here Name of the table being passed Dynamic?

Comment: Do you get an error message when you try to create the trigger. When I try it, I get: `ERROR 1422 (HY000): Explicit or implicit commit is not allowed in stored function or trigger.`

Comment: That's because it's not possible :-)  See my answer below.

Answer (score 8):

As far as I am aware, creating a table inside a trigger is not possible.  See here:

http://forums.mysql.com/read.php?99,121849,122609#msg-122609

Also have a look at the *Restrictions for Stored Functions* section on the [Restrictions on Stored Routines, Triggers, and Events](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/stored-program-restrictions.html) page.