# Create a trigger to create a new table

Tags: mysql, triggers

I'm working on a database that tracks revisions for items. One approach I had in mind was maintaining only two tables: one holding current data and one holding history of said data. My second approach was to have a trigger create a new table whenever there is a new data instead into table that maintains current data.

I haven't found a clear answer to this issue yet but is it possible to have a trigger create a new table?

Let's say I have a table

```
CREATE TABLE items ( 
    item_id INT AUTO_INCREMENT,
    item_type VARCHAR(25),
    item_state INT DEFAULT 1, /* where state is 0 for bad and 1 for good */
    item_date DATE,           /* date item was last checked on */
    PRIMARY KEY (item_id)
)
```

Would it ever be possible to do something like this?

```
CREATE TRIGGER 'new_item' 
AFTER INSERT ON 'db'.'items'
BEGIN
    /* CREATE NEW TABLE FOR ITEM_X */
END
```

Comment: have you tried it? You could have answered it in less time than it took to write the question. also the common method would be to have a table, and an audit table. not fifty million audit tables for fifty million products

Comment: @pala_ It seems like it's not possible after I attempted it, but confirmation from someone else would be nice.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3184059/mysql-create-table-using-trigger